# Where do i find Admob Test Device ID for my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

Where can i find the "Admob Test Device ID" for my iPhone to test the ads?

I search everyone but cannot find something for iPhone..

Comment: SO is a place to dicusss source code. This is not about code. You might try on the Super User site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include AdMob in your project, implement a `GADBanerView` or `GADInterstitial`, and then build and run your project. The Test Device ID will be printed in Xcode's console.

Example of console log:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"e059953b36bf3ad1031d09e8bbd6ac56" ];
```

Then you would add it to your `GADRequest` like so:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "e059953b36bf3ad1031d09e8bbd6ac56"]
```